# How do I fix a circular dependency error?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, circular-dependency, circular-reference

So this is the error I am getting:

```
Workspace must be a tree structure and pass integrity checks
##[error]   ✖ Package dependency cycles audit
##[error]   
##[error] Detected 1 new dependency cycles between workspace packages:
```

Here is the layout of the files that are relevant to this error.

```
packages
  components
     my-component1
        package.json (references my-component2 and data)
     my-component2
        index.ts
     my-component3
        package.json (references data)
  data
     package.json (references my-component2)
```

Do I have to refactor the structure of my project to fix this issue? Does anyone see anything wrong with my project structure?

Comment: From what you listed above, yes `components/my-component1` and `data/packages.json` are a circular dependency since they each "reference" (I assume this means import) each other. You need to refactor.

Comment: So if I removed the reference to my-component2 in data/package.json, and referenced another file somewhere else, this would resolve the issue? And yes by reference I mean like have a dependency listed in that package.json file @sallf

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct folder structure and all references? As I read it there is no circular dependency. Component 2 is the root, connected to data and comp1. Data is a child of comp2 and connected to comp1 and comp3. Comp1 and Comp3 are leafs.

Maybe there are other references present?